# 500 read timeout Selenium : on opening website with large records

Tags: perl, selenium

I am using Perl with Selenium. I have set `$sel->set_timeout("86400000");`.

When opening a website with large content, 500 read timeout message is displayed. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that not the Selenium webdriver (the client) has issued the timeout, but the webserver has been waiting too long.

What do you want to accomplish? Maybe you can just make a HTTP HEAD request to check that your URL is valid? (A HEAD request does not give you any content back, just the HTTP header with the http status code and, optionally, the "Content-Length" header, among other fields. The HEAD request is much faster that a GET or POST request and yo won't have problems with timeouts. You might get more than one HEAD respnses e.g. if your request is redirected to another server.

Or do you want to check the large content itself. Then I cannot help you at this point. There is not enough information.

You can use a Test::WWW::Mechanize object to create the HEAD request (it is a subclass of LWP::Request). NOt sure if selenium supports head requests.

Comment: To follow up on the troubleshooting, can you access the page manually? The 500 error is from the server itself, as it's a HTTP response code. It's not an Selenium error, as far as I know.

If you can provide more information about your test, that would be really helpful.